# Docker giving significantly different image sizes on building again

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I am very new to docker, so I would appreciate any guidelines or best practice suggestions.
So, this is the problem I am facing. I am building an image with the below Dockerfile config.

```
FROM python:3.7.9-slim

RUN apt update && apt-get install -y nginx nano

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 8000

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["gunicorn", "mainapp.wsgi", "-b 0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

I was experimenting with different official Python images. However I am astonished to see that after running the build a few number of times, the image size shoots up from around 100 mb to 400 mb. The problem is, now even if I go back to the previous Python images, the image sizes simply don't go down. Please see the output from 'docker images'.
[image]

So I am trying to go back to the 3.7.9-slim-stretch image which was around 96 mbs. The dates in the output are shown wrong for some reason. My current image which are based on slim and slim-stretch are the top 2 in the output.

Is there something obvious I am missing here? Are there any best practices to avoid this?

Edits: below is the content of the requirements.txt file:

```
asgiref==3.2.10
certifi==2020.6.20
cffi==1.14.0
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.9.2
defusedxml==0.6.0
Django==3.0.8
django-cors-headers==3.4.0
django-rest-auth==0.9.5
djangorestframework==3.11.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.10
joblib==0.16.0
numpy==1.19.1
oauthlib==3.1.0
pandas==1.0.5
Pillow==7.2.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
pycparser==2.20
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.24.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
scikit-learn==0.23.1
scipy==1.5.2
six==1.15.0
sklearn==0.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
threadpoolctl==2.1.0
urllib3==1.25.9
```

Also I performed a docker history  which shows the below output:

[image]

The size of my app folder other wise is 3.5 mbs.

Comment: How big is your application once installed? (after copying `app` files and running `pip install`)

Comment: Can you share the requirements.txt and a rough size estimation of your `/app` directory?

Comment: Okay so after the pip install it adds 284 MBs.

Comment: I have added the requirements file, the app directory is about 3.5 mbs

Comment: 100M of image + 290M of app/pip install + some pip cache (that you might be able to clean after install)... the total size seem quite aligned with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final size of the image is a sum of sizes of all its layers, so as @Zeiyounator stated in his comment to your question, your final size seems about right. There are a few things you can do to make it smaller though.

First remove or disable if possible any unnecessary caches created during package installation.

Second, if you COPY a file and then RUN chmod to change its permissions you create two layers with exactly the same size (you can see that in your `docker history` output). In your case that only wastes 305 B of space, but in general it's a good practice to avoid that by using a [multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) and doing all permission changes in a separate stage.

With all that said, I would rewrite your `Dockerfile` as:

```
FROM python:3.7.9-slim AS init

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

FROM python:3.7.9-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install nginx nano && apt-get -y clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
COPY --from=init /entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["gunicorn", "mainapp.wsgi", "-b 0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Comment: Thanks @Konrad Botor, I did read the comment from Zeiyounator and upvoted it. I was wrongly reading the size of the official images as the docker built images. And your rearrangement of the Dockerfile above in 2 phases is helpful.